# private IP address classes

Tags: ip, ip-address

according to some references Class C for example can provide 2^8 hosts (mask /24), according to others it can provide 2^16 hosts (mask /16).?

so what is the real mask of C class ??

Comment: Mask /8 doesn't mean 2^8 addresses, it's 2^24.

Comment: sorry, I corrected it

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network#Private_IPv4_address_spaces

Comment: http://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/6491/confusing-a-b-c-network-classes

Comment: but operating systems give /24 as mask for the ip 192.168.x.x

Comment: 192.168.x.x isn't a single network, it's 256 separate class C networks.

Comment: so you want to say that 255.255.255.0 is normally the mask of C class

Comment: Reread https://i.stack.imgur.com/U2Qg7.jpg.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from the Protocol IPv4 Specification in [RFC 791](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc791#page-24) publication:

```
Address Formats:

  High Order Bits   Format                           Class  
  ---------------   -------------------------------  -----
        0            7 bits of net, 24 bits of host    a
        10          14 bits of net, 16 bits of host    b
        110         21 bits of net,  8 bits of host    c
        111         escape to extended addressing mode
```

-- [RFC 791 - Addressing](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc791#page-24)

so, for **class C**

```
      address       |  N.N.N.H  (N network bit, H hosts bit)
      mask          |  11111111.11111111.11111111.0000000 (/24)
      # of address  |  256 (2^8)
      # of hosts    |  256 (2^8 – 2)
```

## Update

after rechecking the [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U2Qg7.jpg) that was associated with the OP post, I noticed that his confusion comes from [Reserved IP addresses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reserved_IP_addresses) notion, and precisely the `192.168.0.0/16`address block. and my accepted answer wasn't explaining that properly ^^"

### TL;DR:

192.168.0.0/16 isn't a single C class network number with a /16 host mask, but a set of 256 class C network numbers

### Explanation

given the my original answer.

C class addresses form:

```
  110xxxxx.xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxx
  +------------------------+.+------+
             net               host
```

C class addresses range

```
                 net                host
      +-------------------------+.+------+  
from: 110 00000.00000000.00000000.00000000 (192.0.0.0)  
to  : 110 11111.11111111.11111111.11111111 (223.0.0.0)
      +++ -----.--------.--------.--------
```

form this whole range, there are reserved IP addresses blocks, for various propose. cf. [reserved IP addresses blocks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reserved_IP_addresses)

among this reserved blocks there is:

```
 192.168.0.0 - 192.168.255.255 (192.168/16 prefix)
```

reserved for [Private Network](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network) according to [RFC 1918](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1918#section-3), and defined as: "a set of 256 contiguous class C network numbers.".So:

- 192.168/16
- 192.168.0.0/24 (254 host)
- ...
- 192.168.255.0/24 (254 host)

You can visualize it as:

```
                 net                host
      +-------------------------+.+------+
      +++ -----.--------.--------.--------                     <- C class 
from: 110 00000.10101000.00000000.00000000 (192.168.0.0)  
to  : 110 11111.10101000.11111111.11111111 (192.168.255.255)
      +++ +++++.++++++++.--------.--------                     <- /16 mask
```

Comment: thanks, have you any idea about the origine of the other view (C class = /16)

Comment: a `/16 mask` represents  **class B** according to the guys who defined IPv4 protocol. check the link in my answer. :)